# How to get hour and min from timestamp variable in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp

I got a timestamp variable like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-02-17 17:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'));
```

I've created a trigger and my aim is to get the hour and min from that attribute so that I can compare them in two cursors like **time.cur1 = time.cur2** (supposing that time is hour:min or hour+min), is there any cast like for the date,

```
CAST((timestamp) AS DATE)
```

should I create a new type after extracting the hour and min with

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timestamp) FROM Table;
SELECT EXTRACT(MIN FROM timestamp) FROM Table;
```

or there is another way? (I'm using Oracle Database 11g). Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand.  `EXTRACT()` should work on timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

New type? No, put those values into a `NUMBER` datatype variables.

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_hour   number;
  3    l_min    number;
  4  begin
  5    select extract (hour   from systimestamp),
  6           extract (minute from systimestamp)
  7      into l_hour,
  8           l_min
  9    from dual;
 10
 11    dbms_output.put_line('Hour: ' || l_hour ||'; minute: ' || l_min);
 12  end;
 13  /
Hour: 11; minute: 47

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') AS HOUR, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MI') AS MINUTS FROM DUAL;
```

TO YOUR EXAMPLE:

```
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(HOUR, MINUTS)
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24') AS HOUR, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MI') AS MINUTS;
FROM <EVERY_TABLE_OR_DUAL>;
```